# Display data from mysql row as a column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that I've been struggling with for hours! I'm trying to create a website to display results from a charity scavenger hunt.

I have a table in a mysql database containing my data; the first column contains the name of each person and each subsequent column shows how many of each object they've collected (I've included a pic to explain better anyway).

Table 1:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/U69IqiY.jpg]

I'm trying to use PHP to display this data in a table but I can only represent it the way I've posted in the first picture. I'd like to select a single person's data and display it in a vertical table with two columns, the left column showing the name of each object and the right column showing how many object they've collected (I've put a pic of this in too).

Table 2:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/gverhcw.jpg]

This has been driving me mad for hours so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want `click` in a person name, and then, show the second table, is that? (Honestly, it's confusing to me)

Comment: The first table is just a representation of how the data is stored, with the field names across the top. The second table is how I want to present the data. Sorry if it's confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as long as you know the name = Fred you do this:

```
select * from your_table where name = 'Fred'
```

Then loop through the single result set displaying each of the items.

You'd best show some more code, how you are connecting to the db and so on

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Here is the first bit of code to show how I connect to the database; `<?php
// Connect to DB
$con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","mydb");`
// Get data
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mytable");

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to imgur from work but you'd want to do something like this:

(assuming you bound your results to these variables, of course)

```
echo "<table>"
while($resultsFromQuery->fetch()){
echo "<tr><td colspan=2>".$name."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>item 1</td><td>".$item1."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>item 2</td><td>".$item2."</td></tr>";
...
echo "<tr><td>item n</td><td>".$itemn."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>
```

Comment: Since the OP probably doesn't have enough rep points to add img URL's, have edited the question. Reload to see the changes to the question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the impeded images still reach out to imgur which is blocked at my office.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii-, thanks for adding the image to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I am making assumptions, and please remember to always take a backup of your database before trying new code. Speaking from experience.

If you are using PHP and MySQLi, try the following, if you would like to show a table with all of them, you have that code down, I am assuming you are going to a different page to show the single table fora person.

Here is what I would do, when you click on a name, have it go to a page like `person.php?person=Fred`

here is the code I would use for that page:

```
//Your DB connection details go here.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$_GET[person]'";
$sql_con = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_con);
echo '<h2>Data for '.$data['name'].'</h2><br />';
echo '<table><tr><th>Items</th><th>Count</th></tr><tr>'; // SET UP YOUR TABLE
echo '<td>Item 1</td><td>'.$data['item1'].'</td></tr><tr>';
echo '<td>Item 2</td><td>'.$data['item2'].'</td></tr>'; // CONTINUE FOR EVERY ITEM YOU HAVE
echo '</table>';
```

That should do it, if that is not what you were looking for, let me know.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for replying, this looks like it is going to do exactly what I need! I'm getting a syntax error from the line below where you've set up the table. Any idea what it could be? I've made sure the field names match. Thanks again!

Comment: I made a rookie mistake, try the code again from above.  You will notice I changed the lines from:
`echo '<tr>Item 1</tr><tr>'.$data['item1'].'</tr>;` to `echo '<td>Item 1</td><td>'.$data['item1'].'</td></tr><tr>';` because the rookie mistake was I was creating new rows, and not ending rows. Let me know how that works, if it doesn't work, I will investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for explaining things to me, it really helps as I'm just trying to learn all this at the moment and it's a bit of a steep learning curve!

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error in the same line though, I'll paste all of my code to see if you can see where I'm going wrong. I'm sorry for taking up so much of your time with this!

Comment: `<?php
// Connect to DB
$con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","mydatabase");

//Collect data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = Fred;
$sql_con = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_con);
echo '<h2>Data for '.$data['name'].'</h2><br />';
echo '<table><tr><th>Items</th><th>Count</th></tr><tr>'; // SET UP YOUR TABLE
echo '<td>Item 1</td><td>'.$data['item1'].'</td></tr><tr>';
echo '<td>Item 2</td><td>'.$data['item2'].'</td></tr>'; // CONTINUE FOR EVERY ITEM YOU HAVE
echo '</table>';
 
?>`

Comment: I found the problem, at the end of the SQL script, you need to have an end " (quote) after the SQL.  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Fred'"`  I recommend using apostrophes before and after Fred so it searches for Fred specifically, if you ever have a name with two words (first last) you will need to put it in apostrophes or quotes.

Comment: That's really great, thank you so much for your help!