# Creating a weekly table with hour intervals

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, html-table

I have a "orders" table in which I have a timestamp field so the data looks like this:

```
id | createdate          | customerid 
1  | 2013-10-03 09:35:20 |   5
2  | 2013-10-03 09:35:20 |   9
3  | 2013-10-04 15:00:20 |   5
4  | 2013-10-05 12:15:20 |   5
```

So from this table I need to create an html table that shows Mon-Saturday on top and hours on the side so like this:

```
Hours      |  Monday  | Tuesday  | Wednesday  |  Thursday  |  Friday  | Saturday
9:30 - 10  |    0     |    0     |     0      |     2      |    0     |    0
10-11      |    0     |    0     |     0      |     0      |    0     |    0
11-12      |    0     |    0     |     0      |     0      |    1     |    0
```

So right now what I have so far is this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( createdate,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS createdate
, DATE_FORMAT( createdate,  '%H' ) AS createhour, COUNT( * ) AS totals
FROM  orders
WHERE createdate >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) +6
DAY AND createdate < CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -1
DAY GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( createdate,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) , DATE_FORMAT( createdate,  '%H' )
```

This returns the data but not in the format I need, is there a way to do it in mysql? or does it involve some work in php with arrays?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/19166062/1415724 plus it can be done using a `while` loop. And see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/19119997/1415724

Comment: I'd go to a hybrid solution. Separate by date in SQL and group by the Hours in PHP. Also note the Hours column is not in regular intervals which would make inefficient and hard to read a pure SQL solution

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks but that doesn't help, I know how to get values from mysql into php, thats not a problem for me, but thanks again.

Comment: @MostyMostacho That's what I was thinking of a hybrid solution but still not quite sure what data I need and how it would be separated in php..through arrays?

Comment: @Andres You're welcome. I was under the impression that you wanted it to be formatted in an HTML table, as per your sketch.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea I know how to format it in html just that I don't know how or whats the best way using the data in mysql, as u can see the data is "vertical" and I need the days to be horizontal (columns) not sure if that cleared it up any better..

Comment: @Andres To be honest with you, I'm not that experienced yet to be able to give you the answer you need.